# Hook that act on a field being inserted or updated?

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I've Created a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view to "Modify entity values" .It's working fine. I need to perform an action when particular entity field gets inserted/updated.

So far I've tried [`hook_field_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7.x),[`hook_field_storage_write`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_write/7.x), [`hook_field_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_insert/7.x), [`hook_field_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7.x). None of them are working

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean when the value for a field attached to a particular entity is saved/updated? There's no specific hook, you'd need to listen for `hook_entity_update` and check the value of the field against the original entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [hook_entity_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7.x)? This hook gets triggered as soon as an entity gets updated. Inside the hook you should include some logic with respect to your field.